# Getting error missing artifact in pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                         ERROR--> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Please, can somebody help me in resolving the above error.

Comment: Please share the exact text of the error.

Comment: @Invictus - probably your pom.xml is lacking the `artifactId` tag. Though to confirm please share the complete and exact error.